# Is saving keras models with tf >=2.12.0 not backward compatible?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am struggling with keras' way of saving models in `v2.12.0`. It does not seem to be backward compatible. Am I getting something wrong, or must we refactor code to migrate to `v2.12.0`?

Here is our old way of saving models (`v2.7.0`): Pass valid `.h5` file (!) path to keras, and voilà, a `.h5` file of that name appears on disk:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(...)
model.compile(...)
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

That code now blows up with `v2.12.0`:

```
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: /tmp/tmpt118zg26 is not a directory`.
```

I understand that `v2.12.0` offers 2 options:

- The new way of saving into [folders](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save) is enabled via `tf.saved_model.save()`
- The [old way](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/saving/save_model) of saving to files would still be supported by `tf.keras.saving.save_model`. Apparently, `model.save()` would serve as an alias for `tf.keras.saving.save_model()`

The [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.12.0) also state that

> > Moved all saving-related utilities to a new namespace, `keras.saving`, for example

> > The previous API locations (in `keras.utils` and `keras.models`) will be available indefinitely, but we recommend you update your code to point to the new API locations.

So, then, why does the above code fail all of a sudden?

- Can I still use the "existing approach" to save .h5 directly? If so, how? Is this not supposed to be backward compatible? Do I need to rewrite the code anyway, now (if I want to stick to file writing, do I need to make one-line changes to `tf.keras.saving.save_model()`)?
- Or, must we save into folders, instead of files? Then what's the migration path? All models into one folder, or would they overwrite one another? Do we need to nest folders, then, and also reinvent our way of syncing these models elsewhere (e.g., having to `aws s3 sync 'folder'` instead of `boto3` call `client.upload_file()` to shift the models off to aws)?

Comment: Never assume any version is backwards compatible

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed no backward compatibility. If you have the code for the model, you can still load the weights, even if the HDF5 file contains the full model (saved with `model.save('my_model.h5')`).

First, recreate model architecture, i. e. create the model, but do not train it. Example:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(9, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
                 kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam')
```

Then load weights:

```py
import h5py
from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.hdf5_format import load_weights_from_hdf5_group

with h5py.File('my_model.h5', 'r') as f:
    load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f['model_weights'], model.layers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too after updating Keras to 2.12. Turns out the full path of my script had latin caracters ('ç' and 'õ'), and removing them fixed it. Apparently this version of Keras doesn't accept non-UTF8 characters.